# How to access property of JavaScript object, given string with property's name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

I'm getting this data from a service:

```
{"ok":{"0147852369":"somevalue"}}
```

I need to read the value, which in this example is "somevalue".
Inside a variable I have the string that represents the name of the property containing "somevalue", like:

```
var mobilereceiver = "0147852369";
```

But I can't figure out how to use that string to access the property with the same name.

My latest try is like this:

```
$http.get( 
'url' 
) 
.success(function(data) { 
  var response = angular.fromJson(data); 
  var mobilereceiver = '0147852369'; 
  var messageId = response.ok.mobilereciever; 
});
```

I need to set the last var, `messageId` which should then hold the "somevalue" of the of the data I'm getting from the service. However, it isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at the code you're trying to use:

```
$http.get( 
'url' 
) 
.success(function(data) {
    var response = angular.fromJson(data); 
    var mobilereceiver = '0147852369'; 
    var messageId = response.ok.mobilereciever; 
});
```

You're very close, in that you recognize that your string `mobilereceiver` holds the value that needs to be provided as the name of the final property. However, on your last line, when you try to access `response.ok.mobilereceiver`, that isn't actually referring to the variable `mobilereceiver`. Instead, it's just looking for a property inside `ok` that's actually called `mobilereceiver`. Instead of trying to use the dot notation for accessing properties, what you need to do is use the associative array style accessor:

```
var messageId = response.ok[mobilereceiver];
```

This will allow the actual value of `mobilereceiver` to be passed in as a string, which will be used as the key to look up the value you're trying to access.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to take a look at [angular.fromJson](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.fromJson) which is a helper function that converts JSON data to an object type structure.

Comment: In the now edited form of the question, you'll see that the OP is already using angular.fromJson. This does not solve the question.